# How to get UUID of headphone(earphone) in android?

Tags: android, hardware, uuid, headphones

I am working on a project and I would like to know is there any possibility of getting the UUID of the headphone which is connected to the android device?
If yes then how to do it?
Any help regarding this would be appreciated 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The `UUID` is a unique ID which describes a service provided by the bluetooth handset. If you know which services the headphone provides, there is an overview [here](http://www.bluecove.org/bluecove/apidocs/javax/bluetooth/UUID.html) of the service `UUID`. Otherwise you could download the [Bluetooth Network Scanner](http://www.medieval.it/bluescan-pc/menu-id-72.html) to scan for all the services provided by the headphone.

Inside the Bluetooth Network Scanner application, just press the device, and go to Device Services, and hold the mouse over the service, and the UUID will appear. Like this one:

```
{00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB}
```

which is the UUID of OBEX

Comment: I dont want ID of bluetooth headphone I need the wired headphone's ID